# Disable Ajax when going back from page 2 to 1 with phone's hardware back button - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, mobile

I've got two pages on a Jquery mobile site. On page 1 there's a JavaScript that fires correctly in all cases except when page 2 is reloaded and then the Phone's hardware back button is used to go back to page 1.

There is no issue when I use a back button like: 
    `<a href="#" data-ajax="false"></a>` to go to page 1 after page 2 was reloaded. but with the phone's back button the JavaScript onload event doesn't fire on page 1. The page that has the script needs to be refreshed in order for the script to fire correctly. I've tried many things such as meta tags trying to reload from server, or:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
});
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

None of this works for me. In other words I would like the hardware back button to behave as the `data-ajax="false"` button. 
Any idea how to make the JavaScript onload event fire correctly on page 1 in this case? Many thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `$( document ).ready() { ... }` yet? [link](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Comment: I just tried now `.ready` and no luck...

Comment: So, the issue may not be related to the document load... try adding a `console.log` or an `alert()` to check if it fires or not on `mobileinit()`

Comment: added an `alert("fired");` and it behaves the same way. Will fire the alert only when page 1 is accessed for the first time or refreshed but doesn't fire after reloading page 2  and going back to page 1 with the phone's back button